# jetty-ant.classpath not found error

Tags: java, jetty, playn

I am getting the following warning in eclipse, which is causing jetty to not run and serve my html game:
Reference jetty-ant.classpath not found.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass the custom system property `-Djetty-ant.classpath=<relative folder in your project where the jetty library can be found>` to VM Arguments in Eclipse (if you are using Eclipse). If you don't use Eclipse, you can pass this as a command argument in java compiler.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.  I added it into -vm and -vmargs to no avail.  However, I wasn't exactly sure where the jetty library could be found.  I installed a jetty plugin and it just dropped a lot of jars off in my eclipse plugins directory.  Doesn't maven include jetty?  If not, where do I get the correct jetty plugin and set it up with a playn project?

Comment: Also, if I try to run as web application, I get "[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl"

Comment: Oh, Maven? Probably, there is something wrong with Maven Eclipse's dependency updates for jetty plugin...Sorry, I can't help you with this problem.

Comment: What actions are you taking (i.e. what menu items are you clicking) to run your game via the HTML backend in Eclipse? Maybe you're using the wrong mechanism.